# Virtualbox display driver for Windows 10 only allows 4:3 aspect ratio

Tags: virtualbox, display

1024x768 and 800x600 are the only possible settings. Ubuntu and Fedora both seem to behave this way. So I installed the Extension Pack, which unfortunately had no effect. Is there something else I have to do here?

Comment: Do you mean Windows 10 is the host while Ubuntu and Fedora are the guests? It's a bit confusing. The Extension Pack is only to add [`Support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP and PXE boot for Intel cards.`](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) You need to install the guest addition package(s) on the guests. Make sure the `vboxvideo` kernel module is loaded and X loads the DDX.

Comment: Other way around. I have Virtualbox on my Windows 10 machine and was trying Ubuntu and Fedora on them.

Comment: You seem to have a confusion about host and guest...?